# Dojo popup disappears in less than a second

Tags: dojo

I need some input on an issue. A pop-up is displayed on clicking a dojo drop down. It is a usual behavior. However when drop down is clicked first time, pop-up displays until it is closed but when second time it is clicked, the popup disappears in less than a second.

I get error in Firebug as below

**The ObjectSelector will not fit on screen relative to the anchor and there is a dialog active.  ObjectSelector will be resized to: [152.3000030517578]**

I checked in resolution 1900 X 1080 and I am getting this problem. If I check it in resolution 1600 X 900 the pop-up disappears always before manual closing.

```
 var countryPickerParams = {
        rootId: "root",
        rootTitle: nls["Country"],
        storeUrl: "/cupm/ipt/pmObjectSelectorData.jsp?ENTITY=getCountriesList",
        itemIdField: "id",
        labelField: "countryName",
        iconClassField: "iconClass",
        hasChildrenField: "hasChildren",
        showSearchDropdownMenu: false,
        showToolbar: false,
        showFilterToolbar: true,
        showSelectMessage: true,                  
        selectMessage: "Select Country",
        buttonTitle: "Select Country",
        i18nPackageName: "cupm",
        i18nBundleName: "applicationproperties"
    };
    dijit.byId('country').attr('objectSelectorParams', countryPickerParams);
```

I am new to Dojo, so any assistance would be great. Design shown in attached image. Shading out other fields due to security policy.[image]

Comment: I had to create a similar widget recently. but what I did is use a dijit/form/dropdownmenubutton with a dijit/tooltipdialog which contains the search and countries list. then style the button to look like an input from css. upon contry selection, change the button label and call closeDropDown()

Comment: can you create a sample or jsfiddle for it...

Comment: I am not able to understand.

Comment: The code you have shared is just options, where is the code where the pop-up is show? Is the widget shown in the image a custom widget?